# how to update a recordset in a subform using vb (I am getting error #3426) in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, recordset

I am trying to update a control in a subform.
Actually I am calculating the number of months.
here is the code: (which doesn't work!)

```
 While (Not Me.Form.Recordset.EOF)
months = Round((Me.End - Me.Start) / 30, 0)
Form_FinanceSubform.[number of months] = 0
Me.[number of months] = months
Me.Form.Recordset.MoveNext
Wend
```

the error i get is: "this action was cancelled by an associated object"
on the line Me.Form.Recordset.MoveNext

could someone please help me out here??
thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using a control in the form footer, which should accept =Sum(DateDiff("m",[start],[end])) ?

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow when I am at work! 
thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to use a continuous form.

Comment: im sorry but I think I could explain properly! 
In my subform, there are three columns. Start, End and Number-of-Months!
 Now at the update-event, I want the Number-of-months columns to get the correct number by doing the math to Start and End!! ! 
Start and End are dates.
So the calculation has to be performed each record-set (at event Update! or insert or both! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this part of your code in the form's BeforeUpdate event:

```
months = Round((Me.End - Me.Start) / 30, 0)
Form_FinanceSubform.[number of months] = 0
Me.[number of months] = months
```

I do think you could shorten your code to this:

```
Me.[number of months] = Round((Me.End - Me.Start) / 30, 0)
```

Comment: No problem. I hadn't realized the question was so old already. :)